# PHP Disable download for everyone except who have account

Tags: php

i'm working on a system that will allow download files who have account,
now i have a problem with disabling download from everyone and everywhere,
so any hint or option will be useful thankyou

my codes:

```
global $AllowDownload = false;

function Connect()
{
    $Connect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "12345", "film");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        echo mysqli_connect_error();

    return $Connect;
}

function IsValid($Username, $Password)
{
    $IsValid = false;

    $Query = mysqli_query(Connect(), "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `account` WHERE `username` = '$Username' AND `password` = '$Password'");
    $Check = mysqli_fetch_array($Query);

    if ($Check[0])
        $IsValid = true;

    return $IsValid;
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    exit();
}
else
{
    $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string(Connect(), $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string(Connect(), $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

    if (IsValid($Username, $Password))
    {
        $AllowDownload = true;
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script will have to work as a file proxy in the first place. You can use query parameter to pass the requested file to the script, eg. `proxy.php?file=myfile.jpg`. This is quite nasty and you can greatly improve it by using `.htaccess` file.

The quick sketch of a very simple file proxy might look like this:

```
<?php
  /* authorize user here */

  if(!$authorized) die("No content for you!");
  else {
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    readfile($_GET["file"]);
  }
?>
```

You should however be aware, that like this, a client have access to every file you have on your hosting. You should therefore make sure that you really want to serve that file (at least make sure that user is not trying to change directory with something like `../`.

Please check your `Connect` function. It might probably work with mysqli (it's been long time since I used PHP and especially these low-level functions), but still it's quite nasty. It's definitely better to wrap your connection and form some kind of singleton pattern - something like this:

```
$connection = false;
function connect() {
  global $connection;
  if(!$connection) {
    // connect here
  }

  return $connection
}
```

(this is of course not a correctly implemented singleton - but it makes sure that the connection is initialized just once)

Comment: that part you said should work as proxy works fine now,but users still can download them with direct link, so what way you suggest to prevent users to download them ?

Comment: You will have to place your files either in a directory that is not accessible directly through your web server, or `.htaccess` file is your friend. Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/dVdDeT11) should work. If I haven't mistaken, requests to all non-php files in the directory get redirected to `/files/proxy.php` script.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with following code block. Place the code block within your downloadable valid condition block.

```
if($AllowDownload)
{
    $file = "/your/file/fullpath/filename.jpg";
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

And make sure the real file exist out of the public html directory.

Comment: what about disabling downloads ? which this way user can download files with link like this http://example.com/1990/theif.kmv

Comment: simply put my code in to the place where you want to allow. The place where you make `$IsValid = true;`. In the not allowed potion set the header as you already make `header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');`.